# Prevent scroll to fire on every scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, scroll

I'm trying to use a flag to prevent scroll to fire function each time scroll is triggered. `$(window).unbind("scroll");`since I'm using `.scroll()` with other functions. So why isn't it preventing the function from firing each time?

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        $("iframe").each( function() {
            $this = $(this);
            _src = $this.attr('src');
            _ID = $this.attr('id');
            _yPos = $(window).scrollTop();
            _thisHT = $this.height();
            _thisTop = $this.offset().top;
            _thisBottom = _thisTop + _thisHT;
            _Play = true;

            if (_Play) {
                if( _yPos > _thisTop*0.5 && _yPos < _thisBottom) {       
                    $this.attr('src', _src + '&autoplay=1');
                    _Play=false;

                //$(window).unbind("scroll");
                } else {
                    $this.attr('src', _src);

                }
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: `_Play` is always true.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution, which was pretty obvious. I had to move `_play` outside `$(window).scroll;` and then I used increments instead of true/false (though that probably works to)

```
_play = '0';

 $(window).scroll(function() {

    $("iframe").each( function() {
        $this = $(this);
        _src = $this.attr('src');
        _ID = $this.attr('id');
        _yPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        _thisHT = $this.height();
        _thisTop = $this.offset().top;
        _thisBottom = _thisTop + _thisHT;
        if (_play === '0') {
            if (_yPos > _thisTop*0.5 && _yPos < _thisBottom) {       
                _play = '1';
                $this.attr('src', _src + '&autoplay=1');

            //$(window).unbind("scroll");
            } else {
                $this.attr('src', _src);
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```